# You know the probability that an object is dirty. An unreliable sensor tells you its true state. What is the new probability that the object is dirty?

Tags: probability, statistics, programming, artificial-intelligence

I have encountered a statistics related problem for an AI project that I don't know how to solve, but I'm also nearly statistically illiterate so I'm not sure where to look. Hoping I can get a tip here.

I'll also explain things mostly as a programmer, since if I try to use statistical terms and notation I will likely offend someone.

**Problem**
Suppose you know the probability that an object is dirty: `pDirty`
Then use a dirt sensor which tells you if the object is actually dirty or not dirty.
However, the sensor has a chance to be wrong. You know the probability that the sensor will fail:  `pSensorFail`

With an initial `pDirty`, a sensor value `sensor` (0 or 1), and `pSensorFail`, how should you update `pDirty` given this new information?

**Scenarios**
If `pDirty` is 1 or 0, we already know the dirty state. So we ignore the sensor.
If `pSensorFail` is 0 then the sensor is perfect, and you should set `pDirty` = `sensor`
If `pSensorFail` is 1 then the sensor is still perfect, its just always wrong. You should set `pDirty = 1 - sensor`
If `pSensorFail` is 0.5, then the sensor is basically random and useless, and you should ignore it.

I'm wondering how to handle all other cases?
I assume there is some statistics formula that is correct 8for any `pDirty`, `sensor`, `pSensorFail`

**Experiments**
One strategy to reduce the cases a bit is
if `pSensorFail > 0.5`, set `pSensorFail = 1 - pSensorFail`, `sensor = 1 - sensor`.

Then from this point you can assume `0 <= pSensorFail < 0.5`

I thought of a measure of how much the sensor is "trusted":
`sensorTrust = 2 * abs(pSensorFail - 0.5)`
i.e if `sensorTrust` is 1 then the sensor is always correct, if `sensorTrust` is 0 then it is always wrong

Then I linearly interpolate `pDirty` to `sensor` by `sensorTrust`:
`pDirty = Lerp(pDirty, sensor, sensorTrust)`

This is working okay, but I feel like it doesn't respect the current `pDirty` enough.
For example if `pDirty` is 0 or 1 then we should actually ignore the sensor,
since we are already certain about the dirtiness.
Also, if `pDirty` is 0.5 then maybe the sensor should have an even greater effect?

Any help or tips would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that what you want is the usual Bayesian update: you have $P(D),P(D^c),P(S \mid D),P(S \mid D^c)$ where $D$ is "the object is dirty" and $S$ is "the sensor says that the object is dirty". Then if you get a dirty sensor result, you update your probability that the object is dirty according to

$$P(D \mid S)=\frac{P(S \mid D)P(D)}{P(S \mid D) P(D) + P(S \mid D^c) P(D^c)}.$$

If instead you get a clean sensor result:

$$P(D \mid S^c)=\frac{P(S^c \mid D)P(D)}{P(S^c \mid D)P(D) + P(S^c \mid D^c) P(D^c)}.$$

In your notation, $P(D)$ is pDirty, $P(D^c)$ is 1-pDirty, $P(S \mid D)$ and $P(S^c \mid D^c)$ are both 1-pSensorFail and while $P(S \mid D^c)$ and $P(S^c \mid D)$ are pSensorFail. These formulas correctly manage all the case work you mentioned, including the case when the sensor always gives the wrong answer.

Comment: This is amazing! Its great to see it expressed with proper notation. Thanks a a lot. 

However I am a bit unsure still what $P(D^c)$ refers to?

Comment: $D^c$ is the event that $D$ is *not* dirty. The $^c$ stands for complement.

Comment: Ahh okay. So `1 - pDirty` in my programmer notation.

Comment: Yes, $P(D^c) = 1 - P(D)$.